# SQL Oracle: результирующий запрос(строка)

Tags: sql, oracle

Просьба, подсказать, как можно более универсально выводить результирующую строку (Total:),
для примера, есть таблица

```
select qw, we, rt, fg, ty from t1
```

на данный момент, вывожу строку `Total:` следующим образом,

```
with temp as (select qw, we, rt, fg, ty from t1)
select qw, rt, sum(fg), count(*) from temp
 group by qw, rt
union
select to_char('Total:'), null, sum(fg) from temp
```

это работает, я получаю результирующую строку, но при сортировки в таблице это строка может затеряться, поэтому, хотел спросить, возможно есть более универсальный способ для вычисления данной строки

Comment: В вопросе собственно самый универсальный способ. _но при сортировки в таблице это строка может затеряться_, это не так, с правильной сортировкой ничего не затеряется. Используйте union all и сортируйте явно с order by. Возможно будут интересны и другие способы, см. rollup, grouping set, model.

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо за подсказку, буду пробовать